# How to setup Linux DNS server for Azure VMs in virtual network?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, virtual-machines, azure

I'm trying to use Linux Bind9 to set up a DNS server for my Azure VMs in virtual network. I got one web server and one mail server. My goal is making GoDaddy connect to my own DNS server, and redirect to my web and mail servers. But I failed to doing this. Here is my configurations.

```
My domain: mydomain.com
web server: web.cloudapp.net  IP: 10.0.1.6
mail server: mail.cloudapp.net  IP: 10.0.1.5
dns server: dns.cloudapp.net  IP: 10.0.1.4
**PS**: three servers all in the Azure virtual network.
```

dns.cloudapp.net:

```
/etc/network/interfaces:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.1.0
broadcast 10.0.1.255
gateway 10.0.1.1
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1

/etc/hostname:
dns

/etc/hosts:
10.0.1.4   dns.mydomain.com  dns

/etc/bind/named.conf.local:
zone "mydomain.com" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/zones/db.mydomain.com";
 };

zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.10.0.1";
 };

/etc/bind/zones/db.mydomain.com:
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dns.mydomain.com. mail.mydoamin.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
mydomain.com.   IN      NS      dns.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.    IN      MX      10      mail.mydoamin.com.
mydomain.com.    IN      A       10.0.1.4
dns     IN      A       10.0.1.4
mail      IN      A       10.0.1.5
www     IN      CNAME   web.cloudapp.net.

/etc/bind/zones/db.10.0.1:
$TTL    604800
@     IN      SOA     byc-dev-dns.bringyourchoice.net. byc-dev-em.bringyourchoice.net. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

        IN      NS      byc-dev-dns.
4       IN      PTR     dns.mydoamin.com.
5       IN      PTR     mail.mydoamin.com.
6       IN      PTR     web.cloudapp.net.

/etc/resolv.conf:
Nameserver   10.0.1.4
domain      mydomain.com
search      mydomain.com
**PS**: this file will change each time I restart VM.
```

I've add the public IP address of my dns.cloudapp.net to the NS record in Godaddy.

Can anyone help me with this, and give me some explanations?
Thank You.

Comment: Just curious - are those actually the IP addresses you used? If so then you'll be stuck trying to use them on the public internet because that IP range 10.x.x.x is a private address space that is non-routable from public IP ranges.  Additionally, any domain you put here will require it's authoritative name servers to be updated  to point to your server (see: http://serverfault.com/questions/322443/switching-authoritative-nameservers-how-do-you-set-the-ttl)

Comment: Yes, I'm using these 10s IP address, because these servers are in the same virtual network, I thought I were wrong in this part. @SimonW